# Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token

Tags: php, google-plus-signin

I am trying to fetch user's data from google plus using PHP.
I'm using below tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-65R420rIUA

**Situation:**
User login into my app android using google plus button i fetch the access token using `googleSignInResult.googleSignInAccount.getIdToken()`

I send this token to my server which runs php to fetch users data using google php client (as described in the video)
below is my code

```
try{
            $gClient = new Google_Client();
            $gClient->setApplicationName('pixyfi');
            $gClient->setClientId($config['google']['appid']);
            $gClient->setClientSecret($config['google']['secret']);
            $token = json_encode(array("access_token"=>$lptoken,"refresh_token"=>$lptoken,"token_type"=>"Bearer","expires_in"=>3600,"id_token"=>$lptoken,"created"=>1320790426));

            $gClient->setAccessToken($token);
            $gClient->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);
            $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($gClient);

            $gpUserProfile = $plus->people->get('me');
            echo "User Fetched as:".$gpUserProfile['id'];
        }
        catch(Google_Auth_Exception $x){
            echo "Error:".$x;
        }
```

But i am getting error:
Error:Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_client"
}' in /var/www/html/api/auth/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:364

Could you please let me know what mistake i am making here?

Comment: which kind of field do you store your token in? (is it big enough to hold entire access and refresh token)

Comment: i am not really sure about difference between refresh_token and access_token. From, https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/429#issuecomment-66470720 , it looks like both are same. and yes complete token is being transmitted from android to php server

Answer (score 0):

this is some of my code which handles token thing. Implement this logic and let me know if you are still getting errors.

$row is is fetched from database and contains token information

```
$client->setAccessToken($row['token']);
        if(time()>$row['created']+$row['expires_in'])
        {       
                $client->refreshToken($row['refresh_token']);
                $token=$client->getAccessToken();
                DB::Query("-----UPDATE DB TOKEN INFO-------");
                $client->setAccessToken($token);

        }
```